# Spring JavaConfig vs Annotated Class

Tags: java, spring

How is defining a bean in the JavaConfig different then just annotating a class?

**JavaConfig:**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean () {
        SomeFilter filter = new SomeFilter();

        return SomeFilter;
    }
```

**Annotated Class**

```
@Bean
public class SomeFilter extends FilterRegistrationBean {
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) annotation cannot be applied to a class type. `@Bean` is an annotation processed by a `@Configuration` class parser. It applies to factory methods.

Assuming you meant something like `@Component`, the difference is explicit declaration, where you control the whole instantiation of the bean class and its initialization, versus implicit, where you let the container figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate your bean with say @Component to achieve the same effect as with the @Bean annotation in the Config class. I.e. @Bean explicit bean declaration. @Component implicit (or automatic) bean definition.